# Запуск delayed_jobs и mailman на Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Существует RoR приложение, развернутое на Heroku. Я использую [`mailman gem`](https://github.com/titanous/mailman) для обработки входящий электронных сообщений и [`'delayed_job_active_record' gem`](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) для обработки отложенных заданий (исходящие сообщения via ActionMailer). Для запуска `mailman` процессов на `Heroku` обязательно нужен "Heroku worker" (у меня есть `rake task` с именем `jobs:work`. Этот task запускает `mailman script`). Для запуска процессов 'delayed_jobs' я хочу использовать `Heroku Scheduler` (запускать каждые 10 минут `rake jobs:workoff`). Но когда я запускаю мое приложение на `Heroku` - мой worker запускает `rake jobs:work` и это запускает процессы для `delayed_jobs`, но не запускает `rake task` для `mailman`.

Мой вопрос: Как я могу сконфигурировать `Heroku worker` для запуска другого rake task (это "`bundle exec rake jobs:work`" сейчас) или "исключить этот task из `delayed_jobs`"? Или может быть я могу использовать ОДИН `Heroku worker` для использования обоих этих `gems`?

Answer (score 1):

Привет! Немного не понял ваш вопрос, но рискну ответить.
Если не подключили шедулер в хероку, подключаем:

```
heroku addons:docs scheduler:standard
```

Создаём файлик lib/tasks/scheduler.rake в котором пишем рейк задачи

```
desc "Слава роботам!"
task :glory_robots => :environment do
  puts "Слава роботам!"
end

desc "Убить всех человеков!"
task :kill_all_humans=> :environment do
  Humans.kill_all
  puts "Все человеки убиты, мой господин!"
end
```

Запускать можно так:

```
heroku run rake kill_all_humans
```

Смотреть и задать время шедулерам можно на https://scheduler.heroku.com/dashboard

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но с этим все понятно. главная проблема в том, что для delayed_jobs существует rake task с именем jobs:work, причем эта задача создана не мной, я даже не вижу где она лежит. Но при запуске этой задачи(bundle exec rake jobs:work), запускаются процессы обеспечивающие работу delayed_jobs. То есть на heroku я могу запустить worker(который как раз и обеспечивает bundle exec rake jobs:work, то есть запуск задачи jobs:work). Но обработка задач с помощью delayed_jobs не так критична по времени для меня и я ее повесил на addon scheduler.

Comment: Но у меня есть еще и mailman "сервер", который как раз и требуется держать под worker-ом(обработка входящих сообщений). для запуска скрипта я создал задачу опять же с именем jobs:work, потому что сконфигурировать worker на запуск другой задачи я не могу(второй вопрос как раз об этом). И получается что worker "дергает" bundle exec rake jobs:work, но запускает delayed_jobs, который запускать уже и не надо, он работает под sheduler-ом. и вот два вопроса- как "выключить" у delayed_jobs эту задачу или как переконфигурировать worker на запуск задачи с другим именем.